# Should a person with warts avoid baths to avoid the spread of HPV to other body parts?

Tags: infection, prevention, virus, bath, hpv

The cause of warts in general is the Human papillomavirus, or HPV for short. If I understand it correctly, HPV causes both genital warts and warts on toes. Does this mean that if a person with a wart on his toes takes a bath, the infection can travel via the bathwater to other parts of his body and cause another infection, for example genital warts? Or is the HPV blood borne, and the outbreaks are caused by different factors than skin contact with actual HPV organisms?